What are properties of dynamical systems that are typically hard to prove
In my study of dynamical systems, I have noticed that very often there are basic properties that are easy to prove about a dynamical system, like existence of a periodic orbit, or asymptotic stability.  On the other hand, I have noticed that it is typically very hard to prove things such as ergodicity or mixing.
To this end, I am wondering, given an arbitrary dynamical system -- such as one that exhibits "complex" or "erratic" behavior -- is it usually difficult to prove things like ergodicity, mixing, or even existence of things like dense (transitive) orbits?  Are there any natural or well-known dynamical systems where we do not even know if it exhibits such properties even though we expect them to?

Proving the ergodicity of Thurston's Earthquake Map was a large part of Mizarkhani winning the Fields medal. Proving ergodicity of geodesic flow on negatively curved surfaces requires some careful theory about foliations. Recent major developments in topological dynamics have been proving the existence of (unique!!!) measures of maximal entropy under fairly weak conditions (e.g. transitivity). Almost all billiards maps (in the sense of Baire) are believed ergodic, but this is not known.

Proving existence of periodic points is in general going to be fairly hard, but is made simpler in nice enough cases by (possibly generalizations of) Sharkovsky's Theorem. (Weakly) mixing is often hard for much the same reason as ergodicity... the definitions are similar. Entropy is in general not known to be easily computable (this is an open problem for most systems for both the topological and metric entropies), but contrastingly if known does classify a lot of common systems via Ornstein Theory.
